# When training a neural network with h2o, how do get the history of the reconstruction error?

Tags: r, h2o, autoencoder

I use `h2o` in R to create a neural network, let's say it is an autoencoder. How do get the history of the prediction error, meaning how it evolved over training?

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
nn <- h2o.deeplearning(
  training_frame = as.h2o(iris[,1:4]),
  x=colnames(iris)[1:4],
  autoencoder = TRUE,
  activation = "Tanh",
  verbose = TRUE
)
```

`verbose` does not seem to change anything?

Less important: Once having computed `nn`, how do I find out what its layers are and which layer it assumes to be the latent space?